# How to disable USB pendrive detection at boot on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, module

I boot a remote server that has a USB pendrive plugged.
It creates a shift in the devices names (/dev/sda becomes /dev/sdb, ...) because the USB pendrive is detected before the SCSI disks.
In a normal situation I could manage that at the operating system level but here I must install the server remotely with a quickstart script in a ISO image that I cannot change.
The only settings I have access to are the boot parameters.

How can I prevent the USB pendrive detection ?

Comment: I found it ironic you tagging it ILO. The no-brains approach is evidently disabling it at BIOS level via ILO.

Comment: Yes you are right, It is just that I need to select some options after boot and I'm not sure it will impact the keyboard, I will try anyway, I would have prefered not to disable all USB.

Comment: Do you need any other USB peripheral to work? If you don’t, [this approach](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/414968/86440) should work.

Comment: @StephenKitt  I just found `usb-storage.quirks=VID:PID:i` on https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt

Comment: Ah yes, that looks more appropriate. If it works, you could write your own answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to disable all USB storage devices, these boot options might work for distributions that are using `dracut` their initramfs generator:

```
rd.driver.blacklist=usb-storage,uas
```

And this for distributions using Debian's `initramfs-tools` respectively:

```
blacklist=usb-storage,uas
```

Answer (score 0):

It was long time ago
Identifying the USB ids was a bit difficult, but I manage to by viewing the boot messages and also with `find /sys -ls`  piped to some  grep filter.
In the same time I found a remote help to remove that key so I couldn't test that solution.
In any case this may perhaps helps you to disable an usb device at boot:

Try **usb-storage.quirks=VID:PID:i** kernel parameter as described on [kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt](https://kernel.org/doc/Documentation/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.txt)

Comment: In `usb-storage.quirks=VID:PID:i`, the VID and PID both need to be 4 digit hexadecimal numbers, specifying the vendor and product ID of the USB storage device to ignore. So it works in avoiding one specific pendrive, with known vendor and product IDs.

Comment: Identifying the ID was not easy on a minimal linux environment (almost no tools). I will details here how to do it here.